# Modify symbols inside an expression using the tidy eval framework

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval

I want to replace the function `lazyeval::interp()` using the tidy eval framework. Basically, I have this simple expression :

```r
library(rlang)
expr((a + 5 + b)/3)
#> (a + 5 + b)/3
```

I want to replace this expression so that the `a` and `b` symbols become `c` and `d`, respectively. With lazyeval, it is quite easy :

```r
lazyeval::interp(expr((a + 5 + b)/3), a = expr(c), b = expr(d))
#> (c + 5 + d)/3
```

This function has the `.values` argument allowing to specify either a list or an environment:

```r
lazyeval::interp(expr((a + 5 + b)/3), .values=list(a = expr(c), b = expr(d)))
#> (c + 5 + d)/3
lazyeval::interp(expr((a + 5 + b)/3), .values=as.environment(list(a = expr(c), b = expr(d))))
#> (c + 5 + d)/3
```

I naively thought that I could just replace with the deprecated function `rlang::expr_interp` - or with `rlang::inject()`. That's not the case:

```r
expr_interp(expr((a + 5 + b)/3), as.environment(list(a = expr(c), b = expr(d))))
#> (a + 5 + b)/3
```

I know that I can use the base function substitute for that (like the function interp does), but I would like to figure a way to **modify an expression/call so that a symbol could be replaced by another one with rlang**.

Answer (score 1):

Named interpolation is out of scope for tidyeval.